# Print contents of a form onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I want to print contents of a form onclick of a button .

my view page
here i bind all field data .

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/select2/select2.min.css">

        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="content-wrapper">

                <section class="content-header">
                    <h1>
                        Create Visitors Pass
                    </h1>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admin"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
                    </ol>
                </section>
                <section class="content">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">

                            <div class="box box-info" id="print-area-1">
                                <div class="box-header with-border">
                                    <h3 class="box-title">Fill up Form</h3>
                                </div>

                                <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="box-body" id="dvContents">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-offset-3"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/blank.png" ><div class="clearfix"></div><br>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw"></i>Capture</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/user.png" class="thumbnail" >
                                                <h3>Visitors Photo</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php foreach ($h as $rows) { ?>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                                                    Visitors Name</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" value="<?php echo $rows['visitor_name'] ?>" name="visitor" placeholder="Visitors Name">
                                                </div>                                            
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Department to go </label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">

                                                    <select class="form-control select2"name="dptgo"  style="width: 100%;">
                                                        <option selected="selected"><?php echo $rows['emp_dept'] ?></option>                                               

                                                    </select>                                                
                                                </div>
                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Whom to Meet</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4">

                                                    <select class="form-control select2" name="wtomeet" style="width: 100%;">
                                                        <option selected="selected"><?php echo $rows['emp_name'] ?></option>                                                    
                                                    </select>                                                
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                                                    Name of the Company</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cmpname" value="<?php echo $rows['company_name'] ?>" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Visitors Company">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Associate Person </label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <select class="form-control select2" name="actper" style="width: 100%;">                                                    
                                                        <option><?php echo $rows['associate_person'] ?></option>                                                    
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Visitors Desgn.</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="visdes" value="<?php echo $rows['visitor_design'] ?>" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Purpose to Meet</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input name="meet" class="minimal"  <?=$rows['purpose_to_meet']=="official" ? "checked" : ""?>  type="radio"> Official
                                                        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input name="meet" class="minimal" <?=$rows['purpose_to_meet']=="personal" ? "checked" : ""?>  type="radio"> Personal
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company Address</label>

                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cmpaddrs" value="<?php echo $rows['company_address'] ?>" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Address">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Visitors ID Proof No.</label>

                                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $rows['visitor_id_proff'] ?>" name="idno" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="No.">
                                                </div>
                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Sex </label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input name="sex" class="minimal" <?=$rows['sex']=="male" ? "checked" : ""?> type="radio"> Male
                                                        </label>
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input name="sex" class="minimal" <?=$rows['sex']=="female" ? "checked" : ""?> type="radio"> Female
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Mobile No. </label>

                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mbno" value="<?php echo $rows['phone'] ?>" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Phone No.">
                                                </div>

                                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email ID</label>

                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $rows['email'] ?>" name="email" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>

                                        <div class="box-footer">

                                        <button type="submit" onclick="PrintDiv();" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Print</button>
                                        </div>


                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div></section>
            </div>



        </div>


        <script src="plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function () {

                $(".select2").select2();


                $('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
                });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintDiv() {
        var divContents = document.getElementById("dvContents").innerHTML;
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=200,width=400');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(divContents);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
    }
</script>
```

But when i click on print button print window will open but it shows all fields contents are blank.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
<div id="print-content">
 <form>

  <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="print a div!"/>
</form>
</div>
<script>

function printDiv(divName) {

 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 w=window.open();
 w.document.write(printContents);
 w.print();
 w.close();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i use above script but print window not open.

Comment: i update my answer, it works for me, try this :)